# External display on usb-c doesn't work above 1024px resoultion

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I bought Asus Zenbook Pro ux501vw and DELL DA200 device. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my asus and connect external monitor via HDMI and it works good. When I tried to connect 2nd external Monitor via USB-C ubuntu detected it properly but I have no signal on monitor. When I change resolution to 1024px monitor works good. When I connect this monitor to HDMI port it works in full hd resolution. 
I have no idea how to push this monitor to work in full hd resolution when I connect it to USB-C.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.10*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1920x1200+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: this is likely a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/778824/dell-da200-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu