# External monitor not detected with USB-C adapter

Tags: display, xps, vga, usb-c

I have a Dell XPS 9350 laptop (Ubuntu edition), and am connecting it to an external monitor with a Dell DA200 adapter (USB-C to VGA+HDMI+ethernet), using VGA. It has worked smoothly for months, but since today it is not recognized anymore.

- The screen is OK (tested with another laptop)
- Screen not detected in the All settings > Screen display GUI (it used to work)
- Screen not detected via `xrandr`
- Adapter is detected via `lsusb` (see below)
- Using Ubuntu 16.04 up-to-date, kernel 4.4.0-59
- I hadn't installed new softwares/drivers short before the problem

I don't understand what possibly changed to make it stop working.

In an attempt to fix it, I tried to reboot with/without the USB adapter and/or screen plugged in. No success. I also tried upgrading kernel to 4.8.0-34, but without success either.

Any idea on how to get it back working? What other diagnostic tools can I use?

lsusb output **without** adapter:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:2234 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:0797 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse 200
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Additional lines in lsusb when adapter is plugged in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0617 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
# + same lines as above
```

When adapter is plugged in, nothing is written to /var/log/Xorg.0.log and the following lines are added to `sudo dmesg`:

```
[ 9469.132452] ACPI Error: [SPRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160422/dswload2-330)
[ 9469.132472] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20160422/psobject-227)
[ 9469.132480] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._E42] (Node ffff9d88ae0da460), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160422/psparse-542)
[ 9469.132498] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._E42] (Node ffff9d88ae0da460), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160422/psparse-542)
[ 9469.132520] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, while evaluating GPE method [_E42] (20160422/evgpe-592)
[ 9469.185230] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 9469.185368] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 9469.185370] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 9469.185537] pci 0000:01:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 9469.197071] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 9469.197235] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 9469.197237] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 9469.197403] pci 0000:02:01.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 9469.197594] pci 0000:02:01.0: supports D1 D2
[ 9469.197596] pci 0000:02:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 9469.197825] pci 0000:02:02.0: [8086:1576] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 9469.197969] pci 0000:02:02.0: supports D1 D2
[ 9469.197971] pci 0000:02:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 9469.198128] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
[ 9469.198140] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 9469.198148] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 9469.198243] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[ 9469.198255] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 9469.198379] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
[ 9469.198390] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
[ 9469.198398] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 9469.198546] pci 0000:39:00.0: [8086:15b5] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[ 9469.198573] pci 0000:39:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9f0ffff]
[ 9469.198774] pci 0000:39:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 9469.198776] pci 0000:39:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 9469.198932] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
[ 9469.198943] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
[ 9469.198980] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[ 9469.199020] pci 0000:02:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 04-38] add_size 1000
[ 9469.199042] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 9469.199045] pci 0000:01:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 02-39] add_size 1000
[ 9469.199048] pci 0000:01:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 9469.199050] pci 0000:01:00.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 9469.199054] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 9469.199057] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 9469.199059] pci 0000:02:01.0: res[13]=[io  0x1000-0x1fff] res_to_dev_res add_size 1000 min_align 1000
[ 9469.199062] pci 0000:02:01.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 9469.199064] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[ 9469.199072] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 9469.199083] pci 0000:02:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04-38]
[ 9469.199086] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 9469.199092] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9efffff]
[ 9469.199097] pci 0000:02:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 9469.199105] pci 0000:02:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39]
[ 9469.199112] pci 0000:02:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd9f00000-0xd9ffffff]
[ 9469.199122] pci 0000:01:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-39]
[ 9469.199125] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 9469.199132] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 9469.199137] pci 0000:01:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xc1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 9469.201557] pcieport 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[ 9469.202173] pcieport 0000:02:01.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[ 9469.203012] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[ 9469.203021] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[ 9469.204204] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x00009810
[ 9469.204358] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[ 9469.204360] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 9469.204363] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 9469.204365] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.8.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[ 9469.204367] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
[ 9469.204580] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 9469.204592] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[ 9469.204732] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[ 9469.204738] xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[ 9469.204784] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[ 9469.204787] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 9469.204789] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 9469.204791] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.8.0-34-generic xhci-hcd
[ 9469.204792] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:39:00.0
[ 9469.205179] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 9469.205190] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[ 9469.528994] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 9469.676215] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610
[ 9469.676223] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9469.676227] usb 3-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 9469.676232] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic_2
[ 9469.678309] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 9469.678867] hub 3-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 9469.789093] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 9469.812030] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0617
[ 9469.812041] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9469.812047] usb 4-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[ 9469.812053] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic_2
[ 9469.814751] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 9469.815039] hub 4-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 9470.101125] usb 4-1.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 9470.121806] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[ 9470.121814] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[ 9470.121819] usb 4-1.4: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[ 9470.121823] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 9470.121827] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: 000075000000
[ 9470.209592] usb 4-1.4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 9470.235899] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using pass-thru MAC addr 84:7b:eb:53:ce:0b
[ 9470.293526] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: v1.08.6
[ 9471.335481] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 enx847beb53ce0b: renamed from eth0
[ 9471.358752] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx847beb53ce0b: link is not ready
[ 9471.392388] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx847beb53ce0b: link is not ready
```

Comment: Cable failure? Can you try a different external monitor/tv?

Comment: Indeed, I also thought about that. But the monitor works OK with another computer, and the laptop+adapter doesn't work either with another VGA monitor. Unfortunately I don't have any other computer with USB-C port, so can't test the adapter separately from the laptop.

Comment: Could you please highlight the relevant line in the `lsusb` output or straight out remove all other lines? It's not entirely clear which one is related to the graphics adapter. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` and the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after plugging in the graphics adapter?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I've just edited the question

Comment: Thanks, though I can't make much of it personally. Hopefully someone else has an idea.

Comment: I didn't find much information about it but could this be a docking station with a DisplayLink chipset? The proprietary driver could have been factory installed and now disabled by some kernel update even before you tried 4.8. I'm assuming "Ubuntu Edition" means factory installed Ubuntu. But there are other possibility...

Comment: ... also kernel related but that has to do with the “Alternate Mode” video output functionality of USB3.1, if the adapter relies on that only. There are a couple of results in Fedora forums about the same issue and some kernel versions. It might be worth googling.

Comment: Indeed, the laptop came with a factory install of Ubuntu 14.04, but I did a fresh install of 16.04 when receiving it.

I don't think the DA200 adapter it is a DisplayLink (source: http://askubuntu.com/a/801209/649857).

Actually the device has been working properly on my machine with kernel 4.4.0-59 and then stopped working with the same kernel (i.e. with no kernel upgrade inbetween). So kernel upgrade is not the reason of the bug. And upgrading to 4.8.0 was not a solution.

Didn't see any other solution in Fedora forums :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for the record, the adapter started working again without any software manipulation. I've been playing a bit with the cable, at the junction between the small cable and the adapter. So the problem may have been due to a bad contact in the adapter.

There is now an additional line in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0835:2a01 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd
```

Hope this can help someone else

---

Additional note: 6 month later, while manipulating the cable once more to solve the same problem, I just broke it completely. So be careful and consider returning the adapter to Dell before breaking it, if it is still under warranty.

Comment: I had the same issue, it was solved by plugging in the HDMI after the adapter was plugged in and running.

Comment: Thanks I turned my USB-C cable by 180 degrees and plugged it in again and it works now!

Answer (score 4):

Putting this in the hopes that it might save someone precious time and headache.

**DO NOT assume that just because your laptop has a USB-C port, that it supports external displays over that port!!!**

I have a brand new Lenovo Flex 5i, with 11th gen Intel i5 and Intel iRISxe graphics. Struggled for over an hour trying to get a known good HDMI monitor (which works fine when connected to the laptop's HDMI port) to even be recognized when connected to a new USB-C hub.

Finally, upon reading the Lenovo User Guide, I found where it clearly states that the USB-C port on this computer may only be used for charging and data!

Comment: Hello leka, and welcome to AskUbuntu. Your answer applies to a setup a bit different from the initial question, so it may be easier for others to find it if you create a new question and provide the answer yourself. Thanks for sharing, anyway!

Comment: This was my problem as well. Two USB-C ports. My adaptor was working before then it stopped. I couldn't figure out why. I moved the adaptor to the other port because only one is marked with power so I used that to charge my phone. I didn't realize that it's also the only one to support the video adaptor! I guess that's the difference between TB and USBC, even though they use the same cable.

Answer (score -1):

One reason that USB-C fails to share screen might be a missing driver like DisplayLink. You can download the DisplayLink driver for Ubuntu [here](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu)

Comment: How can I know if I'm missing the DisplayLink drivers?