# Xubuntu 18.04 does not detect external monitors connected via USB-C hub

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, usb-c

I have a Dell Latitude 5490 and two external monitors connected via a USB-C dock (Dell D6000). Both Xubuntu 18.04.1 and Windows 10 are installed on the laptop using dual boot.

The monitors are not detected by Xubuntu but they work fine with Windows 10. I have tried the suggested solution as listed below but with no luck. I have also updated the NVIDIA driver and used the latest one but did not make any difference. No luck with the X.Org X server driver either. Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

[External monitor not detected with USB-C adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879033/external-monitor-not-detected-with-usb-c-adapter)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393560
For this, I have been unable to find the similar option in the bios of my laptop.

[External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

The output from `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    47.99  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell's D6000 dock requires a driver to be installed on Windows, and I note that there is an [equivalent driver available for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads).

This probably isn't the answer for you on Xubuntu given it isn't the standard Ubuntu, but at least it might explain why the dock isn't working in your OS.

Comment: Your solution worked wonder on my Xubuntu. Thank you so much!