# Dell USB-C to HDMI/Ethernet/USB3 adapter - USB 3 port not working anymore on Ubuntu 18.04 - DA200

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb

The DA200 adapter had a problem a while ago, in that the HDMI/DVI ports weren't working on Linux (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778824/dell-da200-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu)). However, the 4.5 kernel update was supposed to solve that.

Now however, the USB port on the adapter stopped working, so I can't connect my mouse/keyboard. On `lsusb`, the adapter shows up as one of:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Not sure which, and not sure why it adds 2 of these Bus Device things (whatever they are).

The HDMI and Ethernet ports on it seem to work. I am running kernel `4.18.16-041816-generic`. I think it started when I tried to use a new keyboard/mouse (using the USB slot on the adapter). Is it possible that it tried to install a driver that is now interfering with it working?

I was wondering if anyone knows how I would start troubleshooting this. For example, is there a way I can check which of ports on the adapter are "recognised" when something is plugged? Or which device it knows are plugged in?

As per the @chilli555 suggestion, I run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, wait a few seconds, and then enter the device - with my screen's HDMI, my mouse's USB-3 (not working), and an Ethernet cable attached to the device. Incidentally, I'm now noticing that the ethernet cable isn't function in either. I get the following long output (sorry):

```
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14294.945349] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14294.945365] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14294.945380] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14294.945390] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.021503] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.023988] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04] is released
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.024122] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-37] is released
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.024222] pci_bus 0000:38: busn_res: [bus 38] is released
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.026080] pci_bus 0000:39: busn_res: [bus 39-6c] is released
Dec 26 18:40:08 telesto kernel: [14295.026266] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03-6c] is released
```

After plugging in the device:

```
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4967
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   92.52  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (44.5 kHz e)
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 4480x1080 stride
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.364091] pci 0000:02:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.364188] pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.364326] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.364330] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365087] pci 0000:03:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365184] pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365321] pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365326] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365545] pci 0000:03:01.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365640] pci 0000:03:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365789] pci 0000:03:01.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.365795] pci 0000:03:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366062] pci 0000:03:02.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366164] pci 0000:03:02.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366315] pci 0000:03:02.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366320] pci 0000:03:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366615] pci 0000:03:04.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366719] pci 0000:03:04.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366877] pci 0000:03:04.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.366883] pci 0000:03:04.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367373] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03-6c]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367394] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xac000000-0xda0fffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367408] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60000000-0xa9ffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367637] pci 0000:03:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367657] pci 0000:03:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367862] pci 0000:03:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05-37]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367881] pci 0000:03:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xac000000-0xc3efffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.367896] pci 0000:03:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60000000-0x7fffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368162] pci 0000:38:00.0: [8086:15d4] type 00 class 0x0c0330
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368222] pci 0000:38:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc3f00000-0xc3f0ffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368346] pci 0000:38:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368533] pci 0000:38:00.0: supports D1 D2
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368540] pci 0000:38:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368955] pci 0000:03:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 38]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.368975] pci 0000:03:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc3f00000-0xc3ffffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369187] pci 0000:03:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39-6c]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369206] pci 0000:03:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9ffffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369221] pci 0000:03:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0xa9ffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369278] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369346] pci 0000:03:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 05-37] add_size 1000
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369368] pci 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 38] add_size 1000
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369377] pci 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 38] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369397] pci 0000:03:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 39-6c] add_size 1000
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369419] pci 0000:02:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 03-6c] add_size 3000
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369431] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369437] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369444] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369450] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369469] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369475] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369481] pci 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369486] pci 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369492] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369497] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369503] pci 0000:03:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369508] pci 0000:03:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369517] pci 0000:03:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369522] pci 0000:03:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369532] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369537] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369543] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369549] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369559] pci 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369564] pci 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369571] pci 0000:03:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369584] pci 0000:03:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xda000000-0xda0fffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369602] pci 0000:03:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05-37]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369614] pci 0000:03:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xac000000-0xc3efffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369624] pci 0000:03:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60000000-0x7fffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369639] pci 0000:03:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 38]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369650] pci 0000:03:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc3f00000-0xc3ffffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369668] pci 0000:03:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 39-6c]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369680] pci 0000:03:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xd9ffffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369690] pci 0000:03:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0xa9ffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369703] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03-6c]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369715] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xac000000-0xda0fffff]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.369724] pci 0000:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x60000000-0xa9ffffff 64bit pref]
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.380080] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.380102] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381314] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381811] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.18
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381818] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381824] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381830] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.18.16-041816-generic xhci-hcd
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.381835] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:38:00.0
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.383505] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.383534] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385652] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385667] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385679] xhci_hcd 0000:38:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385794] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 4.18
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385800] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385806] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385811] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.18.16-041816-generic xhci-hcd
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.385816] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:38:00.0
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.388391] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto kernel: [14302.388420] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto upowerd[1169]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto upowerd[1169]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb4
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto upowerd[1169]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
Dec 26 18:40:15 telesto upowerd[1169]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb3
Dec 26 18:40:17 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4967
Dec 26 18:40:17 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Dec 26 18:40:17 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
Dec 26 18:40:17 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0   92.52  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (44.5 kHz e)
Dec 26 18:40:17 telesto /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1608]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
```

---

UPDATE:

When I have the adapter in already, and I plug in my ethernet cable, there is nothing new registering on `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. When I plug the HDMI cable on the other hand, there's a lot of activity. I noticed this message in `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, which occurred randomly (not after something was plugged in):

```
Dec 27 12:04:45 telesto kernel: [31045.087212] usb usb4-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

When I plug only the USB cable into the adapter port, I get **no new output in `/var/log/syslog`**.

Comment: Please remove the device. Next, run in the terminal: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Insert the device. Then edit your question to show the result. Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c.

Comment: @chili555 I added the output. There are a few `BAR 15: failed to assign [io size 0x1000`, not sure if that's bad. I can't tell if the `usb` part it refers to on some lines is the USB-C on my laptop or the USB3 on the device. However, I can't find any mention of the ethernet "turning on" (and it doesn't work). Also, as I said, I had stuff plugged in, including the screen. A lot of the output might be related to that and might be clouding out the rest. Should I retry without the screen/ethernet plugged in?

Comment: I see nothing whatever here that shows any signs of the ethernet adapter being inserted. Root hub is not the adapter. Does `lsusb` appear the same with or without the adapter? I suspect that your assumption is correct, that the USB port is defective.

Comment: When I enter the adapter/dongle, `lsusb` changes with: `Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`. Plugging things into the adapter doesn't change anything in 'lsusb'.

Comment: I've been playing around with leaving the adapter plugged in and plugging in different cables into the ports. When I plug in HDMI, there's a lot of output in `/var/log/syslog`. When I plug in the ethernet or USB port, there appears to be nothing (occasionally something unrelated pops up). I updated this in my question at the bottom. So essentially, the USB and Ethernet ports seem to have no clue if something is plugged in or not. Is there anything I should look for in `/var/log/syslog` as I'm plugging in the adapter itself, to tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: Didn't we already check syslog as you plugged in the device? Did you read the reviews? https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi-vga-ethernet-usb-30-da200/apd/470-abqn/pc-accessories "This USB Type C adapter is unpredictable. Worked a couple of times then stopped working since."

Comment: I just wanted to isolate which parts of the output were related to the USB port and separate it from the HDMI. Yeah, it seems the adapter doesn't work well on Linux; like I said in the post, it took several years before someone managed to get the HDMI port on it working with Linux. I just wanted to figure out what changed, since it was working before. I guess it's gonna motivate my to learn vim though, now that I can't use an external mouse and keyboard at the same time.

Comment: I've a similar problem on my XPS-13 with Ubuntu 20.10, and it is very annoying.
On top of what Marses describe, I cannot switch off or reboot the laptop if the adapter is plugged in. The shutdown process simply hangs with a black screen but with the lcd light on or with the Dell logo. In both cases the power button led is still white.
I can anyhow have the adapter working if it is plugged in only after I log in to my desktop.
Another strange thing I noticed: lsusb works only as ordinary user not with sudo.